# I do not understand how String arrays are effected by equal signs in this problem (Java)

Tags: arrays, string, equals

```html
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     String[] xy = {"X", "Y"};
     String[] yx = xy;
     yx[0]=xy[1];
     yx[1]=xy[0];
     System.out.println(xy[0] + xy[1]+yx[0]+yx[1]);
    }
}
```

When I run this through Eclipse and other programs it always prints YYYY instead of XYYX how is this? When I began experimenting with the code, I ended up with XXXX when i removed yx[0]=xy[1]. I think it possibly has something to do with the equal signs but I am confused by how it outputs YYYY rather than XYYX.

Comment: Looks like this is homework. Try using println on the result  at each step, instead of printing at the end.

`String xy = {"X", "Y"}; System.out.println(xy);` etc.

Comment: Read this: http://cs-fundamentals.com/java-programming/java-arrays-clone-shallow-deep-copy.php

Comment: @PritamBanerjee Thank you! I now understand how to clone aways with the consequence of refrencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because arrays are references in Java. So assigning `xy` to `yx` makes them the same array. So when you overwrite the first index with `"Y"` they both then have the values `{"Y", "Y"}`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     // xy[0] = "X" and xy[1] = "Y"
     String[] xy = {"X", "Y"};
     // arrays are references, so yx and xy are now the same array
     String[] yx = xy;
     // yx[0] = "Y"
     yx[0]=xy[1];
     // yx[1] = "Y", this is because they refer to the same array
     yx[1]=xy[0];
     System.out.println(xy[0] + xy[1]+yx[0]+yx[1]);
    }
}
```

If you print out both arrays you can see this. Adding this after `yx = xy`:

```
System.out.println(xy);
System.out.println(yx);
```

Will produce some output like this:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@3caeaf62
[Ljava.lang.String;@3caeaf62
```

Comment: Is this due to the fact arrays are objects unlike ints which are primitive types?